# How to parse system time to the input of a program

Tags: batch-file

An alarm program

```
@echo Off
:alarm
start music.mp3

cls
goto alarm
```

How to take/parse system time so that I can make it start alarming at every 15 min or every 1 hour? A complete code would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want some kind of scheduler app for Windows or do you want to know how to parse system date and time in DOS?

Comment: yes i want schedular too so that application runs in background or system tray and gives alarm at speciifed time. Also feel free to give a upvote if you like question :P

Comment: both program works now but the cmd window is irritating me , anyway to start it minimized or trayed to system tray or invisible :P

Comment: The easiest way to avoid the command window is to drop the batch file and use Windows' built-in task scheduler instead.  If you need programmatic control of the task scheduler, you can use the `schtasks` command (at the command prompt or in a batch file) to create, delete, start, stop, reschedule, etc tasks in the task scheduler.

Comment: @bta: There is an API for that if you need programmatic control. No need to use `schtasks` – also comes in handy because on legacy systems `schtasks` doesn't exist; the XP task scheduler is pityful in comparison.

Comment: @Johannes  can u specify that API

Comment: [Search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=msdn+task+scheduler) and you shall [find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get the current minutes:

```
%Time:~3,2%
```

You should then be able to build your IF statement, as follows:

```
IF %Time:~3,2%==00 START music.mp3
```

The only downside is this will keep firing off for the entire duration of the 00 minute.

You could do something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET HasRun=0

:alarm

IF %Time:~3,2%==00 (
   IF %HasRun%==0 (
      SET HasRun=1   
      START music.mp3
      PAUSE
   )
)

IF %Time:~3,2%==01 (
   SET HasRun=0   
)

CLS

GOTO alarm
```

The gist of it is when the minutes = 00 (the first of the hour), we start the MP3, and then let the system know the alarm has run.  One minute after the hour, we reset the HasRun flag so that the next hour, the alarm can start again.

It's fairly clunky, though, since the batch file will be constantly grinding away.

Comment: in the above code what does 00 indicate, is it 00 for hour , min or secs

Comment: The 00 indicates the minutes, so you could do 15, 30, 45, etc. and handle quarter intervals.

Comment: Thanks mate , %Time:~3,2%==00 , why  3 and 2 ???
 ,(or please put comments in code)

Comment: %TIME% returns HH:NN:SS.mm format.  ~3,2 tells us to start at the third character, and read 2 characters to the right.  If the time were 12:00:01.25, we'd get "00".

Answer (score 0):

The following code will take a timestamp and convert it into a number of minutes since midnight.

```
REM store current timestamp
set now=%TIME:~0,-6%

REM Break time apart into hour and minute
set hour=%now:~0,-3%
set min=%now:~-2%

REM convert hour and minute into minutes
set /a starttime=((%hour% * 60) + %min%)
```

To do what you are trying to do, you would use the above code to take a "start" timestamp.  Add the desired number of minutes to the result (`set /a endtime=(%starttime% + %interval%)`).  Now, create a loop that will get the current time, use the above code to convert it into a number of minutes, and then compare it to `%endtime%`.  If the two match, then the desired number of minutes has elapsed.

Note that this will not behave as expected if the time interval crosses midnight (that is, if the start time is at the end of one day and the end time is at the start of another day).

Of course, the easier way to solve this problem is to use a program like `sleep` that was designed to do just this.  You can get one from the Windows 2003 Resource Kit (details [here](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html)) or from the [GNU Coreutils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) package.

**Update:**
If what you really want is simply a task scheduler, then use the Task Scheduler that is built into Windows (Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks, details [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/) or [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)) or the command line version (the [`at`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true) or [`schtasks`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx) commands).